# persist with many to many doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a problem using Doctrine with many to many relation when I persist my data.

I have 2 entities :
- Bloc
- Job

I retrieve my ID's before the persist with `getJobs()` method.

```
$bloc = $form->getData();
// $bloc->getJobs() works I retrieve good IDs with foreach getId()

$em->persist($bloc);
$em->flush();
```

My method addJob :

```
/**
 * Add jobs
 *
 * @param Job $jobs
 * @return Bloc
 */
public function addJob(Job $jobs)
{
    $this->jobs[] = $jobs;

    return $this;
}
```

My form:

```
$bloc = $em->getRepository('Acme\\Entity\\Bloc')->find($id);

    $form = $this->createForm(BlocType::class, $bloc);

    $form->handleRequest();

    if($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $bloc = $form->getData();

        $em->persist($bloc);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlashMessage('edit', "Update message");
    }
```

But the persist add new line in my job entity instead of use line already in my database.

Any idea?

Comment: can you provide more informations about your entities ? And also your controller action, form collection, ...

Comment: I updated. Do you want more?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `$jobs` is a `Collection` of `Job`, so you should implements methods to handle this collection.

If your entity declarations are correct (oneToMany, ManyToOne, uni/bi directional) you should have something like this :

```
class Bloc
{
    // ...
    protected $jobs;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->jobs = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getJobs() 
    {
        return $this->jobs;
    }

    public function setJobs($jobs)
    {
        $this->jobs = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

        foreach ($jobs as $job) {
            $this->addJob($job);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addJob(Job $job)
    {
        if (!$this->jobs->contains($job) {
            $this->jobs->add($job);
            // if needed for bi directional way
            // $job->setBloc($this);
        }
    }

    public function removeJob(Job $job) 
    {
        // if you want
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already similar entity. Getters and setters are generated with Doctrine command. Exactly jobs is a collection of `job`. I added constraint unique true on my slug value in my job entity and I have this error :  _1062 Duplicate entry 'value_slug' for key 'UNIQ_A0C4F1C5989D9B62' in ...doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:105_

Comment: Are your sure you handle correctly the collection ? This error seems to say "no". When the form is submitted, `addJob` and `removeJob` should be used to handle the collection. Are these methods called ?